# Network bandwidth usage per process

Tags: linux, networking, system-monitoring

On Linux (preferably in the command line), how can I view network usage per process?

I'm not interested in total bandwith usage, but rather in how it's split among processes.

Comment: [nethogs](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs) might work for you

Comment: Sorry, man. I missed the comment. @Oliver should have it....

Comment: @It don't matter. You made it an answer. Meaningless score points go to you. :) (The accepted checkmark remains to be Oliver's for the taking, should he choose to compete with you ;))

Comment: Ok. Though frustratingly enough, they do have significance until you get to 200 points, because they block us from commenting!  (200 points will put you over 100 on all the SE sites, which solves that irritation.)

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368002/network-usage-top-htop-on-linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install nethogs
sudo nethogs
```

From the man page:

> NetHogs is a small 'net top' tool. Instead of breaking the traffic down per protocol or per subnet, like most such tools do,  it  groups  band‐width  by  process - and does not rely on a special kernel module to be loaded. So if there's suddenly a lot of network traffic, you  can  fire up  NetHogs  and immediately see which PID is causing this, and if it' some kind of spinning process, kill it.